# Differences/merging two files

Tags: shell, awk

I have two lists of IP addresses. I need to merge them into three files, the intersection, those from list1 only and those from list2 only.

can I do this with awk/diff or any other simple unix command? How?

The files look like this:

```
111.222.333.444
111.222.333.445
111.222.333.448
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are sorted then

```
join list1 list2
```

will output the intersection.

```
join -v 1 list1 list2
```

will output the ones that are in list1 only.

```
join -v 2 list1 list2
```

will output the ones that are in list2 only.

Answer (score 2):

First sort them, using sort, and then you can use [comm](http://ss64.com/bash/comm.html).

Intersection:
`comm -12 <file1> <file2>`

List 1 Only:
`comm -23 <file1> <file2>`

List 2 Only
`comm -13 <file1> <file2>`

Comment: Or just plan "comm <file1> <file2>", giving three columns, with "file 1 only", "file 2 only" and "common" (as long as the input files are sorted).